# kalman filter parameter identification

Tags: python, prediction, kalman-filter

I'm doing a project on traffic flow prediction using Kalman filter, the difficulty I've come across is regarding Kalman filter parameters.

these are the state prediction model and the flow observation equations:
x(k+1) =M(k).x(k)+w(k); z(k) = H.x(k)+v(k)
how can I find M(k), H, w(k), v(k)?

Comment: M is defined by your system dynamics, w is the process noise, and v is the measurement noise. It is hard to define them without defining your system dynamics first.

Comment: in this [documentation](https://filterpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kalman/KalmanFilter.html) I couldn't find  `M(k)`, `w(k)`, `v(k)` explicitly too except `H`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the equations for your traffic flow model, you can modify them to fit the state prediction and observation models.
If you have differential equations, they need to be discretized first. [Check this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretization).
H relates to which states you want to observe from the state vector x.
Measurement noise v(k) and process noise w(k) have covariances which are to be tuned by you to achieve the best estimation.
Refer to the book: Kalman Filtering by Grewal and Andrews.